# Reproducing ZPE corrections to adsorption from literature

Tags: phonons, adsorption, zero-point-energy

**Background**

In [this](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/156/15/154113/2841068/An-assessment-of-density-functionals-for?redirectedFrom=fulltext) paper by Lee, *et al.*, they are looking at different functionals and dispersion corrections and how they change the predicted value of CO$_2$ chemisorption on an amine-functionalized metal-organic framework. In the [supplemental information](https://pubs.aip.org/jcp/article-supplement/2841068/zip/154113_1_epaps/), they give the different computed phonon frequencies for each functional and/or dispersion correction for gaseous CO$_2$, the amine (m2m) on the MOF, and the final, chemisorbed amine with CO$_2$.

Table II on page 7 of the paper gives their computed ZPEs and thermal energy corrections for each method.

I am trying to use the data given in the SI to confirm I get the same numbers as they do for the ZPE and TE.

**Problem**

My understanding is that the ZPE correction for this system should simply be calculated as

$\Delta E_{ZPE} = \frac{1}{2}(\sum_i \omega_{i,m2m+CO_2} - \sum_i \omega_{i,m2m} - \sum_i \omega_{i,CO_2})$.

$\omega_{i,m2m+CO_2}$ are the phonon frequencies for the m2m + CO$_2$ system [section CO2-m2m of Table SIII], $\omega_{i,m2m}$ are the phonon frequencies for just m2m [section m2m of Table SIII], and $\omega_{i,CO_2}$ are the gaseous phonon frequencies for CO$_2$ [section CO2 of Table SII].

However, when I do the arithmetic, my numbers come out wrong. They list the ZPE to be 6.6 kJ/mol, but the above math gives me 5.6 kJ/mol. This is a small difference in the scheme of things, but since I am using their exact reported numbers, I would expect to get basically the same values.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 CO2 in the unit cell, so to calculate the binding energy and also the zero point energy per CO2, you have you do 6*E_b = E_{MOF-CO2} - (E_{MOF} + 6 * E_{CO2}). I think equation 3 is just a typo. Applying this to the ZPE might fix the discrepancy that you see.

Comment: If this is what "might" fix the problem,  and your answer is so short that it fits in a comment (`There are 6 CO2 in the unit cell, so to calculate the binding energy and also the zero point energy per CO2, you have you do 6*E_b = E_{MOF-CO2} - (E_{MOF} + 6 * E_{CO2}). I think equation 3 is just a typo. Applying this to the ZPE might fix the discrepancy that you see)` it would be best to leave a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @AGS. I had thought of that, but since they only compute the phonons for one of the m2m/CO2 sites (the other 5 are equivalent), that is already taken care of. I do have to use that trick to reproduce their binding energies, though.

Comment: So you have 63 modes for the bound CO2 to the diamine appended MOF, 54 modes for the diamine appended MOF without CO2, and 4 modes for gas phase CO2 (in table S2)? It looks like that’s what your original post is saying you did.

Comment: Also which functional are you calculating it for?

Comment: @AGS that’s correct. I can reproduce their frequencies with the correct number of eigenvalues but when I sum them up as described above, I get different numbers. I have also loaded their numbers in a spreadsheet and summed them up and still see the discrepancy. I’m doing the PBE to start.

Comment: That is strange. Is it important that you reproduce their number exactly, or are you just looking to make sure you understand how to do the calculation? It’s possible there’s a small mistake on either end. Maybe trying to test the ZPE for a different functional and comparing yours with theirs would help you see if there was just something weird about the PBE result

Comment: When I look at a different calculation (PBE+GD3), I still get a discrepancy (my computed ZPE is 6.6 kJ/mol and theirs is 7.3 kJ/mol). Again, very small difference, but given that I'm computing these numbers based on their reported phonon frequencies, I would expect that they would align almost perfectly. Indeed, the main thing is that I want to make sure I understand how they doing the calculation.

Comment: Yeah, this is strange. From my experience with similar calculations it sounds like you are doing it correctly, but I also would have expected perfect agreement. At this point it might be worth just emailing the first author and seeing if they can clarify the discrepancy.